# setState inside componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, branch.io

I'm trying to wait for data in `componentDidMount` and then change my state `isLoading` to false  but `setState` is not triggering. I'm able to console.log the data inside `branch.init` but I don't know why `setState` is not working.

```
    state = {
      isLoading: true,
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      console.log("componentDidMount");

      let branchKeyTest = 'key_test_aBcDeF'

      branch.init(branchKeyTest, function(err, data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 1))

        this.setState({ isLoading: false })

        if (data && data.data_parsed) {
          switch (data.data_parsed.link_type) {
            case 'new_release':
              localStorage.setItem('redirect', JSON.stringify({
                'link_type': 'new_release',
                'release_id': data.data_parsed.release_id
              }));
              break;
            default:
              console.log("do nothing")
          }
        }
      })
    }


  render() {
    const { isLoading } = this.state;
    if (!isLoading) {
      return (
        <div>Done Loading</div>
      )
    else {
      return (
        <div>Still Loading</div>
      )
    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`branch.init(branchKeyTest, function(err, data) {` needs to be changed to `branch.init(branchKeyTest, (err, data) => {` because you don't have access to the class's `this` keyword inside the anonymous function.

The way you wrote it, you don't have access to `this` because `this` was referring to the function's context - not the class. By changing it to fat arrow syntax, you can access `this` for the React class's context.

You can read more about [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/1913185).